# Writing a regex to detect repeat-characters

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regex, that would identify a word that have a **repeating character set** at the **end**. According to the following code fragment, the repeating character set is `An`. I need to write a regex so this will be spotted and displayed.

According to the following code, `\\w` will match any word character (including digit, letter, or special character). But i only want to identify english characters.

```
String stringToMatch = "IranAnAn";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w)\\1+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToMatch);
if (m.find())
{
    System.out.println("Word contains duplicate characters " + m.group(1));
}
```

UPDATE

```
Word contains duplicate characters a
Word contains duplicate characters a
Word contains duplicate characters An
```

Comment: How many characters is considered "repeating"? Do you want to flag `banana` (although it's a valid word) and `mama` (only repeating sets). How about `zoo` - repeating a single character - or `tomtom` (repeating three characters). If you want a match of "just English characters", use `[A-Za-z]` for the character to match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to catch as many characters in your set as possible, so instead of `(\\w)` you should use `(\\w+)` and you want the sequence to be at the end, so you need to add `$` (and I have removed the `+` after `\\1` which is not useful to detect repetition: only one repetition is needed):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\1$");
```

Your program then outputs `An` as expected.

Finally, if you only want to capture ascii characters, you can use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `\\w`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)\\1$");
```

And if you want the character set to be at least 2 characters:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]{2,})\\1$");
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. i have added the output i have given. It also detects the `a` as well. I only want to detect consecutive characters.

Comment: @sharonHwk I'm not sure I understand. I thought that with the input `IranAnAn`, you expected to find `An` - is that not what you meant? In your update, why would `a` be considered as a repeating character?

Comment: I only want it to output when it detects a repeating `An`. But it outputs when it detects a repeating `a`.

Comment: @sharonHwk Maybe instead `+` try using `{2,}`

Comment: Hmm yes, that seemed to work. But can you tell me what `{2,}` means? Thanks

Comment: @sharonHwk It means the length of the repeating character set must be 2 or more. If you want to ignore single characters that are repeated, then that is the way.

Comment: @sharonHwk `+` means that element can repeat one or more times, `{2}` means exactly two times, `{1,4}` means between one or four times, `{2,}` means two or more times, or in other words at least two times. More info at http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: `{2,}` matches at least two characters, while `+` matches at least one character

Answer (score 1):

If by "only English characters" you mean A-Z and a-z, the follow regex will work:

```
".*([A-Za-z]{2,})\\1$"
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. i have added the output i have given. It also detects the `a` as well. I only want to detect consecutive characters.

Comment: In [unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/#0060) between `A` and `z` there are also other characters like `[` \ `]` `^` `_` `\``. `[A-Za-z]` is more precise.