# Find the repeating substring a string is composed of, if it exists

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pattern-matching

How would you go about splitting a normal string in to as many identical pieces as possible whilst using all characters. For example

```
a = "abab"
```

Would return `"ab"`, whereas with

```
b= "ababc"
```

It would return `"ababc"`, as it can't be split into identical pieces using all letters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count occurrence of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: @ObsidianAge no, that's not a duplicate. This question is looking for repeating substrings, not a character count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very similar, but not identical, to [How can I tell if a string repeats itself in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29481088) – the difference being that that question only asks to determine whether a string is made up of identical repeating substrings, rather than what the repeating substring (if any) is.

The accepted (and by far the [best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29482936) performing) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29489919) to that question can be adapted to return the repeating string if there is one:

```
def repeater(s):
    i = (s+s)[1:-1].find(s)
    if i == -1:
        return s
    else:
        return s[:i+1]
```

Examples:

```
>>> repeater('abab')
'ab'
>>> repeater('ababc')
'ababc'
>>> repeater('xyz' * 1000000)
'xyz'
>>> repeater('xyz' * 50 + 'q')
'xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzq'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that repeating substring has no pre and after letters, so it also could be this way:

```
In[4]: re.sub(r'^([a-z]+)\1$',r'\1','abab')
Out[4]: 'ab'
In[5]: re.sub(r'^([a-z]+)\1$',r'\1','ababc')
Out[5]: 'ababc'
```

([a-z]+) means substring, \1 means repeat.

**EDIT :**

```
re.sub(r'^([a-z]+)\1{1,}$',r'\1','abcabcabcabc')
'abc'
```

Comment: This only works if the substring is repeated exactly once.  It wouldn't work for `ababab`.

Comment: Edit for multiple repeating.