# Need to make a list by splitting the given string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Input string has 'n' times of X. `Like this "XXXXX"`
Need to split the string and make out a list in which each character of the string(X) is each element of list.

Constraints:
0 <= X <= any number
**'n'** is unknown

**Example 1**: X is 12,

Input string : `"121212121212121212"` 
Output list : `[12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12]`

**Example 2**: X is 2,

Input string : `"2222"` 
Output list : `[2,2,2,2]`

**Example 3**: X is 489,

Input string : `"489489489"` 
Output list : `[489,489,489]`

I tried this approach
`my_list = list(input_string)`

I am getting output like,
`[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]`

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

**Edit 1: I am new to stackoverflow. Please help me to edit this question properly.**

**Edit 2: As this question is clear and understandable, please consider upvoting.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the repeating substring a string is composed of, if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035406/find-the-repeating-substring-a-string-is-composed-of-if-it-exists)

Comment: Please clarify your question if possible.  Do you want to generate two-character pairs in a list always?  Or, do you want to break up a string into like sequences of characters?  E.g. would `123123` become `[123, 123]`, or would it become `[12, 31, 23]` ?

Comment: Since X is known as to the latest edit, my answer below should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decode this string you need 'n' and X anyway.
Why not build it directly with:

```
li = [X] * n
```

Edit:
If you don't have 'n', you could get it easily from the given string.
(Under the condition that givenString only consist of X)

```
n = len(givenString) / len(str(X))
li = [X] * n
```

Comment: I don't know "n" beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re 

x = input('Enter Your X : ')
mystr = input('Enter Your Input String : ')

result = re.findall(x, mystr) 
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```
Enter Your X : 12
Enter Your Input String : 121212121212
['12', '12', '12', '12', '12', '12']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant that makes sure the substrings all match the given pattern:

```
input_ = "121212121212121212"
x = "12"
res = []
while input_.startswith(x):
    res.append(x)
    input_ = input_[len(x):]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `X` is also unknown, you can use this:

```
import textwrap

def find_shortest_pattern(input_):
     for len_ in range(1, int(len(input_) / 2) + 1):
          patterns = textwrap.wrap(input_, len_)
          if all(pattern == patterns[0] for pattern in patterns):
               return patterns[0]

find_shortest_pattern("123123123")
```