# Split text by pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a string and spits out the number of repeated patterns:

```
string1="abcabc"

string 2="abcdabcdabcd"

solution(string1)=2

solution(string2)=3
```

My code is below. It works for most cases but I'm still failing a hidden test case (last one out of 10)

```
def solution(s):
    final_score=[]
    for x in range(1,50,1):
        pattern=s[0:x]
        repeats=[(s[i:i+x]) for i in range(x,len(s),x)]
        #print(pattern,repeats)
        if all(pattern in x for x in repeats):
            #print(len(repeats))
            final_score.append(len(repeats)+1)
        else:
            continue
    #print(final_score)
    return(max(final_score))
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!

Edit: For the case of "abababab", or where multiple patterns are available ("ab" and "abab"), I'm trying to return the highest frequency (in this case, "ab" repeats 4 times, so the function should return 4)

Comment: Are you not able to find out what the final case is? Is it possible that it is to do with runtime

Comment: Your code returns 1 for `aaazaaa`, but I was expecting to see 2.

Comment: What is the expected output for `abababab`?  Is that four repetitions of `ab`, or two repetitions of `abab`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035406/find-the-repeating-substring-a-string-is-composed-of-if-it-exists

Comment: Welcome to SO! Also see https://www.codewars.com/kata/5491689aff74b9b292000334

Comment: @JohnGordon I need the maximum frequency of patterns. So "abababab" should read "ab" with the highest frequency (4) and return 4

Also, "aaazaaa" should return 1 because there is only 1 pattern available ("aaazaaa" itself)

Comment: Is it possible that the last test case has a non-repeating value in the first character of the string? It seems like you assume all patterns are present at the beginning of the string, but you haven't provided a problem statement to require that.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible to do this via regex - assuming, at least, that the string consists *only* of one repeated pattern.

```
import re

def solution(string):
    match = re.match(r'(.+?)\1+', string)  # matches an arbitrary-length pattern,
                                           # followed by at least one repetition
    if match:
        pattern = match.group(1)           # extract which pattern was repeated
        return len(string) // len(pattern) # number of repetitions
    else:
        return 1                           # or whatever your case is for if there  
                                           # are no repeated patterns
```

The regex is written non-greedy, so it will use the smallest possible pattern it finds. Though, this will work incorrectly if the pattern is repeated once, but then followed by something that isn't a full repetition. Maybe try `re.fullmatch()` if this is a problem.

Comment: Fails the "aaazaaa" example, so yeah, use fullmatch.

Answer (score 0):

Making Python do the hard work:

```
>>> for s in 'abcabc', 'abcdabcdabcd', 'abababab', 'aaazaaa':
        print(s, len(s) // (s+s).find(s, 1))

abcabc 2
abcdabcdabcd 3
abababab 4
aaazaaa 1
```

Based on [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/repeated-substring-pattern/discuss/94334/Easy-python-solution-with-explaination).