# Capture repeated characters and split using Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to split a string by using repeated characters.

For example:

My string is "howhowhow"

I need output as 'how,how,how'.

I cant use 'how' directly in my reg exp. because my input varies. I should check the string whether it is repeating the character and need to split that characters.

Comment: howhowhow have you done it so far?

Comment: Regex lookahead match and replace.
also, please see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for good questions. Good luck.

Comment: Related: [How can I tell if a string repeats itself in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481088/how-can-i-tell-if-a-string-repeats-itself-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

string = "howhowhow"

print(','.join(re.findall(re.search(r"(.+?)\1", string).group(1), string)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
howhowhow -> how,how,how
howhowhowhow -> how,how,how,how
testhowhowhow -> how,how,how  # not clearly defined by OP
```

The pattern is non-greedy so that `howhowhowhow` doesn't map to `howhow,howhow` which is also legitimate.  Remove the `?` if you prefer the longest match.

Answer (score 0):

```
lengthofRepeatedChar = 3
str1 = 'howhowhow'
HowmanyTimesRepeated = int(len(str1)/lengthofRepeatedChar)
((str1[:lengthofRepeatedChar]+',')*HowmanyTimesRepeated)[:-1]
'how,how,how'
```

Works When u know the length of repeated characters

Comment: And if the word is `testhowhowhow`, it outputs `tes,tes,tes,tes`