# Check if python list elemnts respect a pattern

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like :

```
L = [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

I want to check if the sequence 2-1-2 is always respected or I have an outlier somewhere .
Is there a simple way to do this with python ?

Comment: This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481088/how-can-i-tell-if-a-string-repeats-itself-in-python) is about strings, but it might be helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import cycle

L = [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

seq = cycle([2, 1])

for idx, el in enumerate(L):
    if not el == next(seq):
        raise ValueError(f"Sequence not followed at index {idx}")
```

Answer (score 0):

What does "2-1-2 is always respected" mean, precisely?

I assume you want to check if `L`is an alternating sequence of `2` and `1`, starting with `2`.

That's easy to check:

```
def check(L):
    if len(L) < 3:
        return False
    even_indices_all_two = set(L[::2]) == {2}
    odd_indices_all_one = set(L[1::2]) == {1}
    return even_indices_all_two and odd_indices_all_one and L[-1] == 2
```

- If you don't require `L` to end with `2`, remove the `and L[-1] == 2`.
- If you wonder about the many colons, check [this post to understand slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295).
- I use the [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to check if a sequence contains only one distinct item.